# Eliminar registro con su imagen

Tags: base-de-datos, imagen, archivo

tengo una consulta, alguien sabe como eliminar una imagen conjunto con un registro que se encuentra guardada en la carpeta public? la cual la envie a travez de un formulario, me explico:

> El usuario "id= 2" relleno el formulario subiendo una foto de perfil (la cual se va a public), pero al eliminar su usuario, no elimina la foto de perfil de la carpeta public, solo elimina el registro de la BD.

Espero su respuesta adjunto codigo.

HTML BOTON ELIMINAR

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{action('vehiculosController@destroy', $listado->id)}}" >
{{csrf_field()}}
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('¿Esta Seguro?')" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  </button>
</form>
```

VEHICULOSCONTROLLER

CREATE

```js
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $nuevoVehiculo = new Vehiculos();
        $nuevoVehiculo -> patente = $request -> patente;
        $nuevoVehiculo -> p_circulacion = $request -> p_circulacion;
        $nuevoVehiculo -> r_tecnica = $request -> r_tecnica;
        $nuevoVehiculo -> img_r_tecnica = $request -> img_r_tecnica;
        $nuevoVehiculo -> img_p_circulacion = $request -> img_p_circulacion;
        $nuevoVehiculo -> descripcion = $request -> descripcion;
    
        $post = Vehiculos::create($request->all());
        //IMAGEN
        if ($request->file('img_p_circulacion')) {
            $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',$request->file('img_p_circulacion'));
            $post->fill(['file'=> asset($path)])->save();
        }
        return redirect()->route('vehiculos.index');
    }
```

ELIMINAR

```js
public function destroy($id)
{
Vehiculos::find($id)->delete();
return redirect()->route('vehiculos.index')->with('success','Registro eliminado satisfactoriamente');
}
```

IMAGEN TABLA BD
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la base de datos guardas la ubicación del archivo (el path)? O de otro modo ¿cómo sabes que imagen es de que registro de la base de datos? Edita la pregunta y agrega esta infomración.

Comment: perdon, hay edite la pregunta, agrege la tabla de la BD y me gurda la "RUTA" como archivo ".tmp" lo cual tampoco se si esta bien, pero cuando voy a la carpeta public me aparece la imagen

Comment: ES un problema de orden de cosas. Primero buscas el registro, borras el archivo del disco y despues borras el registro de la base de datos.

Comment: y como seria el cod para borrar el del disk?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#deleting-files